# How do I expose a single api controller in azure?

Tags: azure, powerbi

I have an app with a blazor ui for humans, and I added a single api controller for a tool (power bi) to call so it can access some of the data the app parses

the app uses microsoft identity for authentication, and the controller has custom auth to let in requests with an api key, and locally it works fine, ui redirects to login, api controller returns invalid key etc and lets in calls with the right key in the header, but in azure the whole thing is locked

How do I expose just the ....azurewebsites.net/api route?

As a sidenote since power bi is an azure tool (I know very little about power bi) is there a way to give it permission via azure to avoid the custom auth route?

Answer (score 0):

Since I had custom auth all I needed was an authorization.json file

```
{
  "globalValidation": {
    "requireAuthentication": true,
    "unauthenticatedClientAction": "RedirectToLoginPage",
    "redirectToProvider": "azureactivedirectory",
    **"excludedPaths": [
      "/api"
    ]**
  }
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-file-based